# Css style not getting applied to javascript template literal

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm getting an API response from the node backend which I then want to display on my HTML page using javascript template literals. Styles for the body, HTML, and some HTML content  do get applied  ut the styles for that page do not get applied to data that is being rendered using template literals and appears as plain html tags on screen.

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Movies</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/homepage.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <section id="section">
      <div id="g"></div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_img">
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621570170764-306af40c39eb?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=60"
            alt=""
            class="movie_poster"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="movie_title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
          <div class="movie_desc">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos
            temporibus aliquam pariatur consequatur, exercitationem ex? Nulla
            aperiam architecto illum, similique sint minus velit culpa nesciunt
            corporis at distinctio possimus a.
          </div>
          <div class="movie_extra_details">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script>
      try {
        fetch("/home/movies", {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({ page_number: 1 }),
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            auth_token: localStorage.getItem("jwtToken"),
          },
        })
          .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            show_movies_list(data);
          });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      function show_movies_list({ message: { results } }) {
        for (let index = 1; index < 2; index++) {
          const element = results[index];
          const { poster_path, overview, title, id, original_language, adult } =
            element;
          let cdds = `
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_img">
          <img
            src= ${poster_path}
            alt=""
            class="movie_poster"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="movie_title">${title}</p>
          <div class="movie_desc">
            ${overview}
          </div>
          <div class="movie_extra_details">
            ${original_language} ${adult ? "Adult" : "UA"}
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
          `;
          document.getElementById("g").append(cdds);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
.card-body {
  display: none;
  padding: 5%;
}
.card_img img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
.card:hover {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  height: auto;
}
.card:hover .card-body {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

OUTPUTS

[image]

Do y'all need to node backend code too

Comment: [`append`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) doesn’t take HTML strings; all strings will be appended as text nodes. You may want to use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead. Read the documentation. Why do you assume that the CSS styles do not get applied here? The text is not parsed as HTML; there is nothing to apply CSS to. The CSS works perfectly fine.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+html+string+%22.append%22+-jquery) of [Append html element to the DOM instead of string of html](/q/53746340/4642212) and (more generically) [duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+append+html+string) of [Appending HTML string to the DOM](/q/7327056/4642212).